# js problem with focus input and clear it while i focus

Tags: javascript, input, focus

When I focus on input in js through a button on the keyboard, after focus the input is not empty, but with this button, delays do not work

```
let popAddFlag = false;
let popAdd = document.querySelector("#popWrite");
let popAddName = document.querySelector("#name");
let popAddDescription = document.querySelector("#description");
let dark = document.querySelector("#dark");
const popAddOpen = function(){
    popAdd.style.display = "flex";
    dark.style.display = "block";
    popAddName.focus();
    popAddFlag = true;
}
addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
    if (e.code.toLowerCase() === "keyn") { //n
        document.querySelector(".newArticle").style.opacity = "1";
        if (!popAddFlag) {popAddOpen();}
    }
    
});
```